# oracle allocate value with priority

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got table like that:

```
    | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | ID | PRIORITY |
    |-------|--------|----|----------|
    | 150   | 190    | 1  | 3        |
    | 150   | 90     | 1  | 6        |
    | 150   | 10     | 1  | 2        |
```

I'd like to have table like that:

```
    | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | ID | PRIORITY |
    |-------|--------|----|----------|
    | 140   | 190    | 1  | 3        |
    | 0     | 90     | 1  | 6        |
    | 10    | 10     | 1  | 2        |
```

I need to figure out an PL/SQL code that allocates `VALUE2` to `VALUE1` with priorities from `PRIORITY` column. `VALUE1` per `ID` it's always the same in my example it is a number 150. I write step by step what I'd like achive, maybe it'll be easier to understand;

1. `PRIORITY` = 2 has `VALUE2` = 10, so `VALUE1` = 10,
2. `PRIORITY` = 3 has `VALUE2` = 190, so `VALUE1` = 140, because sum of column `VALUE1` per one `ID` can't be higher then 150,
3. `PRIORITY` = 6 has `VALUE2` = 90, but`VALUE1` = 0, because `VALUE1` reached value 150 with `PRIORITY` = 3.

It could happen that one `ID` will have the same 'PRIORITY' in that case code should divide `VALUE2` proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think a cumulative sum and some comparisons:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(value2) over (order by priority) - value2 < value1
             then value1
             when sum(value2) over (order by priority) > value1
             then 0
             else value1 - sum(value2) over (order by priority)
        end) as allocated_value
from t
```

You can also use `greatest()` and `least()` to make the logic more convoluted:

```
select greatest(least(value1 - sum(value2) over (order by priority), value2), 0)
from t;
```